# Is it possible to generate the test coverage for a project using Jest which is tested with Chai JS?

Tags: jestjs, chai

I have a project which has various unit tests running successfully using chai js.

Is it possible to use Jest and generate the coverage for this project without rewriting unit tests with Jest JS?

Please provide any documentation to support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do so without rewriting unit tests with Jest JS.
You can search for plugins otherwise

Answer (score 0):

It isn't because Jest has no way to understand your Chai tests.

You will have to migrate them to Jest. As their interfaces are pretty much similar it will not be a painful task.

Airbnb details why and how they do it from Mocha to Jest on a large codebase in this [Medium post](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/unlocking-test-performance-migrating-from-mocha-to-jest-2796c508ec50).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to migrate from chai using `jest-codemods`. However you might have to rewrite some configurations and tests(for version compatibility). You can automate changes to your codebase through this.

Please go through these links for further details.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/migration-guide

https://github.com/skovhus/jest-codemods